# Getting the xmlns value with Jackson XML?

Tags: java, xml-namespaces, jackson-dataformat-xml

I'm currently trying to get **xmlns** value. I need to validate xml files. I'm using Jackson-dataformat-xml to deserialize xml files to objects. So far I've not found a way to get that value.

@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true) does not seem to be working for xmlns.

**xml**

```
<Document xmlns="urn:...">
...
</Document>
```

**Java**

```
@Data
public class Document {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String xmlns;
}
```

As I understand xmlns isn't exposed as a attribute. Is there any I could get the value somehow with Jackson?

Comment: I don't know if you are still interested but probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616890/jackson-xml-deserialization-of-namespaces-attr.ibutes-to-object/72620098#72620098) can help.

Answer (score 0):

**xmlns** value is namespace declarations. it's not a attributes but metadata, so parsers do not expose them as attributes.

Comment: I see... But is there a way to get xmlns value through Jackson?

Comment: even I need the answer how to read th xmln value