# Jackson XML deserialization of namespaces attributes to object

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, xml-namespaces, jackson-databind

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "model_trees")
public class ModelTrees {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true, localName = "xmlns")
    private String some_text1;
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "tree_kind")
    private String treeKind;
}

XML:
<model_trees xmlns="http://test.com/test1">
       <tree_kind>kind</tree_kind>
</model_trees>
```

after deserialization:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
ModelTrees modelTrees = xmlMapper.readValue(xml, ModelTrees.class);
```

I get field some_text1 with null value.
But if I replace "xmlns" with attribute "id" everywhere, then I get the value I need (http://test.com/test1)

How to deserialize "xmlns" namespace attribute with XmlMapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to deserialize "xmlns" namespace attribute with XmlMapper?

This is not normally possible because namespace declarations are not attributes but metadata, so the standard `XmlMapper` mapper ignores them as attributes. To achieve your goal you can instantiate a new mapper turning off the namespace support so the namespace will be reported as a regular attribute, so you need to construct a new mapper with the proper settings passing a [`XMLInputFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html?is-external=true) factory:

```
//instantiate a factory without namespace support
XMLInputFactory inputF = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
inputF.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, false);

//instantiate a mapper without namespace support
//then namespace will be reported as a regular attribute
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper(inputF);
ModelTrees modelTrees = mapper.readValue(xmlMapper, ModelTrees.class);
```